# Eco / Stand-by / Spindown settings for LaCie Rugged Triple USB 3?

Tags: external-hard-drive, hdparm

I have two *LaCie Rugged Triple USB 3* external HDDs connected to a powered USB hub. When my Mac is 'on,' the drives are managed by macOS and go into stand-by correctly. But when the Mac is off, the drives spin up and never enter a stand-by mode; LaCie state that they have an "Eco mode," but there's no documentation regards this.

If they have power, they run constantly.

So is there a way to set stand-by / spindown on the drives themselves?

I've looked at hdparm, but I don't understand the options and parameters.

Thanks.

P.S. I did install "LaCie Desktop Manager" but the drives don't show up, they're unsupported.

Comment: +1 for clear, concise description of issue